# Using plot() in R and obtaining a line connecting the points when I want to have dots

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the residuals of a model in R and I am obtaining a line plot instad. Can you help me? I don't wish to connect the points.

```
residuals <- as.data.frame(fit$residuals)
row.names(residuals)<- NULL
plot(residuals$x, axes=F, xlab="", ylab= "Residuals")
Axis(side=2, labels=T)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: `plot(residuals$x, axes=F, xlab="", ylab= "Residuals", type = "p")`